# Re-initializing OmniFocus for Mac

Tags: mac, omnifocus

Is there a straightforward way to create a new database for OmniFocus for Mac?  My current database is spaghetti.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "reinitialize" you mean get rid of the old database and start fresh then yes, you can.

- Navigate to `~/Library/Application Support/OmniFocus` where ~ stands for your home directory.
- You should find `OmniFocus.ofocus` within that location.

If you want to blow it all away and start over, simply delete this file while OmniFocus is closed, when it is reopened it will generate a new database file fresh.

If you are having trouble with some other aspect of the database, like the file size being massive or something like that, take a look at this blog post, it may have some information you would want. http://gtdmarc.blogspot.com/2008/07/fixing-constantly-growing-omnifocus.html